# Angular Firebase orderBy date

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a question, I hope you can guide me, I am working in an angular application with Firestore and I need to order by date but i have this error.

> The query requires an index.

This is my query code

```
getListByTwoParam(fieldName: string, value1: string,fieldName2:string,value2:string): Observable<Array<T>> {
   this.baseCollection = this.db.collection<T>(this.path, ref => ref.where(fieldName, '==', value1).where(fieldName2,'==',value2).orderBy('date'));
       return this.baseCollection.snapshotChanges()
         .pipe(
           map((d) => {
              return d.map((action) => {
                const data = action.payload.doc.data();
                return ({id: action.payload.doc.id, ...data}) as T;
           });
        }),
        catchError(this.myErr.handleError)
  );
}
```

The date field is a timestamp in firebase with this format

```
16 de julio de 2020, 20:56:43 UTC-5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message comes with a link to the Firestore console.  It will prompt you to create an index that will satisfy that query.